# com.facebook.ads.internal.util.common.ANActivityLifecycleCallbacksListener.ANActivityLifecycleCallbacksListener null pointer exception

Tags: facebook, ads

I am using the Audience Network Library version 6.11.0. I am getting this null pointer exception. I checked this function and found this one. It seems the context is null. That is why I am getting this , but I am initialising from an application class, so it should not be null. If anyone has any idea, please tell me how to solve this.

com.facebook.ads.internal.util.common.ANActivityLifecycleCallbacksListener.ANActivityLifecycleCallbacksListener null pointer exception

public static void registerActivityCallbacks(Context context) {
Context application = context.getApplicationContext();

}

Answer (score 0):

[check here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/android/initialize-sdk). Latest implementation of FB Audience network init.